# match country name - return country code

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm working on a client shipping project in JavaScript where the customer selects shipping "collection_country" and "destination_country" - these are passed through to pre-populate an address form on the following page.

I am trying to integrate a web service that will only recognize the country code in 3 letter iso3 format.

I need to create an array of countries - check for the country name in both "collection_country" and "destination_country" and return the iso3 code as the following code is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var ctrl;

      function CapturePlusLoaded(control) {
          ctrl = control;
          ctrl.setCountry("<?php echo $_POST['destination_country']; ?>");
      }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, this is my first question so feel free to grill me for whatever I've done wrong :)

Comment: That's not enough for us to see what's going on - what has the form submitted in `$_POST['destination_country']` and what is passed to `CapturePlusLoaded` as `control`?

Comment: 'destination_country' is the country name value, can be anything. Really I just need to know how to check an array for a country name match, and return another value.

Comment: Well how it's done depends on what you have and how it's laid out. If you have an array of names and array of codes where keys match up, you could run `.indexOf()` on the names array, and use that key to get the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I have figured this out by retrieving the value of both "collection_country" and "destination_country" fields, using a separate web service to retrieve the iso code of that country name and passing that value into the country select function. This has avoided the need for a large array of countries :)

Many thanks for your comments